# how to display a countdown timer

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I can't figure out how to do this.
I have a button and once it's tapped I want to start a process in five seconds and while the user is waiting i want to show the count down - 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

I can't get this to work i've tried using nstimer but that doesn't work.
Any suggestions?
Thankds

Comment: NSTimer does work. You should post your code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dispatch_after()` and take advantage of the way blocks capture scope to keep track of how many seconds left you have.

```
- (IBAction)buttonHandler:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.countingDown)
        return;

    [self startCountDown];
}

- (void)startCountDown
{
    self.countingDown = YES;
    self.button.enabled = NO;
    int seconds = 5;
    [self countDownFor:seconds];
}


- (void)countDownFor:(int)seconds
{
    self.countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds];
    if (seconds == 0) {
        self.countingDown = NO;
        self.button.enabled = YES;
        return; 
    }

    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self countDownFor:(seconds - 1)];
    });
}
```

Comment: PS. i changed button.enabled to buttonEnabled

Comment: Can you please give a swift version of the answer please. @CarlVeazey

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution with GCD and blocks:

```
    __block void (^runBlock)(int) = ^(int i) {
        countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        if(i>0) {
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1*NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                runBlock(i-1);
            });
        } else {
            runBlock = nil; // Breaking retain cycle
            // Time to start your great action!
            // ...
        }
    };

    runBlock(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                       target:self
                                     selector:@selector(methodNameUsedToupdateButtonText)
                                     userInfo:nil
                                      repeats:YES];
```

and invalidate the timer if countdown reaches 0 (and if view unloads)

check [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)